Does an asymptotically stationary curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with vanishing acceleration imply vanishing velocity?
Looking for a proof or a counterexample: for twice continuously differentiable curves $\vec{x}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$
, does
$$\left( \lim_{t \to \infty} \vec{x}(t) = \vec{L} \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{t \to \infty} \vec{x}''(t) = \vec{0} \right)$$
imply
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \vec{x}'(t) = \vec{0}?$$
My attempt at the problem: Neither of these conditions by themselves are enough to guarantee the result, since if we only had the first we could take $x(t) = \frac{\sin(t^4)}{t^2 + 1}$, and if we only had the second one, since $x''(t) = \frac{1}{t}$ with integral $ln(t)$ is continuous on $[1, \infty)$ and the integral over $[1, \infty)$ diverges, we should be able to smoothly interpolate this to the left, then integrate that twice to get a valid $x(t)$ counterexample in 1-D. However, I haven't been able to find a counterexample assuming both hypotheses, and I'm not sure whether the statement should be true or untrue, even just in 1-D.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Don't pay attention to that bot. Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions and  PSQs.
